# How do i ungroup all nodes for all materials in a directory of blender projects from an external python script?

Tags: scripting

Im having an issue with a python script that need to go into all the blender projects in a directory, and remove all node groups from all materials. however I get an error saying "None type does have bpy.data.node_groups".

````
import bpy
import os

directory = "D:/cooper bower/3d stuff/assets"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".blend"): 
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            
            bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=filepath)

            for node_group in bpy.data.node_groups:
                if node_group.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeTree':
                    node_group.use_fake_user = False
                    bpy.data.node_groups.remove(node_group)

            bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```
````